# flask and flask-wtf - Error for previously submitted form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a flask form where when a "driving distance" checkbox is selected and the form is submitted, the user goes to a new page that asks for your address. However, when the second form is submitted, I am sent back to the first form page.

I printed `form.errors` after running `form.validate_on_submit()` and the first form submits fine. The second one seems to be submitting on load and it raises:

```
{'address': ['This field is required.']}
```

And when I enter an input and submit the second form, I get an error for a required field on the first form.

This is as best as I can recreate the code in the minimal amount of specificity:

forms.py

```py
class MainForm(FlaskForm):
    states = TextAreaField(
            'States', 
            validators=[
                DataRequired(), 
                Length(min=4, max=471)
                ],
            render_kw={
                'rows': '10', 
                'cols': '77'
                }
            )
    driving_distance = BooleanField(
        'Driving Distance',
        render_kw={'class': 'checkbox'}
    )

    # showDiv is a javascript function that hides the regular page contents and displays a loading screen
    submit = SubmitField('Find Competitions Near You', render_kw={'onclick': 'showDiv()'})  

class AddressForm(FlaskForm):
    address = StringField(
        'Address or Coordinates:', 
        validators=[DataRequired()],
        render_kw={'size': '79'}
        )

    submit = SubmitField('Submit Address', render_kw={'onclick': 'showDiv()'})
```

app.py

```py
@app.route("/output")
def output_page(states, address=False):

    if address:
        output = backend_function(states, address)
    else:
        output = backend_function(states)

    return render_template('output.html', output=output)


@app.route("/address", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def address_form_page(states):
    form = AddressForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return output_page(states, form.address.data)

    return render_template('address.html', form=form)


@app.route("/form", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main_form_page()
    form = MainForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        states = [state.strip() for state in states.data.split('\n')]
        if form.driving_distance.data:
            return address_form_page(states)

    return render_template('main_form.html', form=form)
```

main_form.html

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.states.label() }}
    {{ form.states() }}
    {{ form.submit() }}
</form>
```

address.html

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.address.label() }}
    {{ form.address() }}
    {{ form.submit() }}
</form>
```

What I think is happening is that my url is still that of the original form when I submit it and it sends me to the new form, therefore it is reloading and expecting new inputs to the form I already submitted. I think this would be solved by using the `redirect()` function from flask, but I don't know how to do that while giving inputs to address_page. If this seems to be the case, how can I give those inputs to address_page while using the redirect function, or avoid using that function entirely?

Another speculation I have is that the second form is submitting on load, and if so, how can I change that? I thought that this could be happening because of a "use current location" option that used the `navigator.geolocation` api to find your coordinates, but this kept happening even when I disabled that.

One last interesting thing to note is that when I have no input to the address form and I submit, rather than getting an error, it starts loading for what seems to be forever.

**UPDATE**

I checked to see if my first speculation was correct by sending the form input form the main form to global variables that were accessed by the address form function that way instead of as arguments, and it worked, except that it thought that the inputs to the first form were empty.

Comment: What is your form tag method set to? I think `POST` may solve what you're describing, but I'd need to see a larger example of your code to be sure.

Comment: @Ryan_IRL My form element has the attribute ```method="POST"```. As for more code I can add the code for the forms if you like, but there are a lot of things that would need to be explained if I included the whole app file. Should I do so anyway?

Comment: Your description isn't bad, but if you're able to make a minimal example that reproduces the issue, it would certainly help (and may serve as a sanity check for you?).